# java linked lists, order two arrays to print

Tags: java, list

I would like to help me I'm doing the method to display lists linked with nodes, and I stumbled to print the list in order as they were admitted not know how to do it, maybe ordering the two arrays at a time as they have the same index, thanks

```
* @author Deibis
 */
public class ListasEnlazadas {

     private int dato;
     private int puntero;
     private int L;
     private int disponible;
     private int[] Datos= new int[20];
     private int[] Next= new int[20];

     public ListasEnlazadas(){
         this.disponible=0;
         this.L=-1;
         this.puntero=1;
     }

     public void InsertarElemento(int dato)
     {
        if(disponible<Datos.length)
        {
          Datos[disponible]=dato;
          Next[disponible]=puntero;
          disponible= puntero++;

        }
     }

     public void EliminarElemento(int Elemento)throws Exception
     {
         int posDato=-1;
         for (int i = 0; i < Datos.length; i++) {
             if(Datos[i]==Elemento){
                 posDato=i;
                 Datos[i]=0;
                 disponible=i;
                 Next[i]=-1;
                 break;
             }
         }
         if(posDato==-1)throw new Exception("NOT ELEMENT IN TO LIST");
         else System.out.println("ELEMENT DELETE TO LIST");
     }

     public void MostrarElementos()
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < Next.length; i++) {
             System.out.println("DATO : "+ Datos[i] + "  SIGUIENTE : " + Next[i]);
         }
         System.out.println("Dato["+disponible+"]");  

         // METHOD PARA ORDENAR 
         // FROM
           /* DATO : 12  SIGUIENTE : 1
            DATO : 13  SIGUIENTE : 2
            DATO : 90  SIGUIENTE : 6
            DATO : 20  SIGUIENTE : 4
            DATO : 50  SIGUIENTE : 5  */

         //TO 

         /* DATO : 12  SIGUIENTE : 1
            DATO : 13  SIGUIENTE : 2
            DATO : 20  SIGUIENTE : 4
            DATO : 50  SIGUIENTE : 5
            DATO : 90  SIGUIENTE : 6  */
     }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a small running example for us so that we are able to rebuild what you are trying to achive

Comment: @KevinEsche at the end of the code in method MostrarElementos is an example of what I do, I want to order while the two arrays and then to print the way you want

Comment: So you want to sort it?

Comment: @Mr.Joel if the value of `DATO` is the highest possible, like 90 in your example, would `SIGUIENTE` also provide the highest value in that case?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[])

Comment: @kevin Esche if for example, you should initialize as something possible, but there is some way to order both at the same time? since following data refers to the shor method was watching but still do not know if you can apply here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Arrays.sort` method to sort the array into ascending numerical order.

However I really suggest creating a class for this.

```
public class Elemento implements Comparable<Elemento> {
    public int Dato;
    public int Siguiente;

    public Elemento(int dato, int siguiente) {
         this.Dato = dato;
         this.Siguiente = siguiente;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Elemento compare) {
        return this.Siguiente - compare.Siguiente;
    }   
}
```

Make an array containing these objects. Using the `Arrays.sort` method will sort it comparing Siguiente.
Or, if you make a `List`, use the `Collections.sort` method.

Comment: whether it does compare, just order a settlement in this case the following arrangement?

Comment: which makes this method than described, because it refers to a single array, intended to use the two

Comment: Using two arrays isn't ideal.  If on one of the arrays a value occurs more than once. It will make the sort, not sort as it should, as it is linked to another value.

Comment: if repeated no problem because I want to print in the order as they were admitted to the array data and for this I refer to the following arrangement, the two form a node in a linked list, I suggest a method to make this different than I think?

Comment: After sorting, all indexes are different So it would be impossible to know what the index was, pre-sorting. Just use the class I suggested, change the `compareTo` method to sort on Dato and you are done.

Comment: not forget that my data and following variables are of type array

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is now. I posted an answer.... just take the advice

Comment: Thanks, anyway you have a reference node linked list type in java? implemented with arrangements?